# How to retrieve information about a transaction just performed?

Tags: php, paypal, omnipay

This is my code:

```
$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('PayPal_Express');
    $gateway->setUsername('name');
    $gateway->setPassword('pass');
    $gateway->setSignature('sig');
    $gateway->setTestMode(true);

    $resp = $gateway->purchase(
            array(
                'cancelUrl' => 'mysite/',
                'returnUrl' => 'mysite/success',
                'description' => "mysite item",
                'amount' => $amount, //final amount
                'currency' => 'EUR'
                )
            )->send();

    if ($resp->isSuccessful()) {
        // payment was successful: update database
        // never reached
        $a = new database('database');
        $a->write database;
        $dbp = null; die;
        print_r($resp);
    } elseif ($resp->isRedirect()) {
        // redirect to offsite payment gateway
        $resp->redirect();
    } else {
        echo $resp->getMessage();
        header('Location: mysite/error');
        exit;
    }
```

How can I retrive informations about the transaction after the redirect?
How to adapt this code for credit card on paypal?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I would assume that you're not getting to the successful payment stage.

With this in mind, let's take a look at the express checkout flow and compare it to a DoDirectPayment api call

===============

1. SetExpressCheckout API Call - the Shopping Cart announces the checkout details and gets back an "Express Checkout Token". The token identifies the checkout session that the shop has requested from PayPal
2. The buyer is redirected to the Express Checkout URL and the token gets appended to the redirect URL - https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6C677292NP7377708

(if you skip step 5, you have to add a useraction=commit parameter to the redirect URL)

4. The buyer logs in and approves the payment
5. The buyer is redirected back to the Return URL announced in the SetExpressCheckout API call with the PayerID and the Token added to the return URL as HTTP GET Parameters

5. The integration initiates a GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call, retrieves the shipping info and displays one last overview and the added shipping charges to the buyer

6. Once the buyer decides to complete the payment, he initiates the payment through your integration on your website. The website then calls the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API

===============

For Credit Card Payments via the DoDirectPayment API, the API NVP Request and Response would look like this - it should be pretty straight forward.

```
Request:  
VERSION = 109.0  
METHOD = DoDirectPayment  
PAYMENTACTION = Sale  
IPADDRESS = 192.168.0.1  
AMT = 0.01  
CREDITCARDTYPE = Visa  
ACCT = xxxxxxxx6840  
EXPDATE = 102020  
CVV2 = 123  
FIRSTNAME = John  
LASTNAME = Test  
STREET = 12312 Port Grace Blvd  
CITY = La Vista  
STATE = NE  
COUNTRYCODE = US  
ZIP = 68128      
CURRENCYCODE = USD  

Response:
TIMESTAMP=2015-01-20T16:00:27Z  
CORRELATIONID=180513f33ad52  
ACK=Success  
VERSION=109.0  
BUILD=14726230  
AMT=0.01  
CURRENCYCODE=USD  
AVSCODE=X  
CVV2MATCH=M  
TRANSACTIONID=0PA61839GE498951M}
```

===============

Judging by your comments in the code, you're assuming that the transaction completes once step 4 is complete.

As I do not see any code to initiate a DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call, you will need to make sure at least step 6 is being done.

https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ has standalone sample code that might help.
However, using an SDK based integration will relieve much of the pain:

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

...

If you want to retrieve Payment Details at a later stage, you can run a GetTransactionDetails API call against the Transaction ID returned in the DoDirectPayment API call or the DoExpressCheckoutPayment calls.

See: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Further, may I suggest using the REST based api interfaces? They're much more streamlined:

Paypal Account Payment (Express): https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal?interactive=ON&env=sandbox  
  
Credit Card Payment (DoDirect): https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_creditcard?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instant Payment Notification to receive notifications about the just completed transaction. [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) is the recommended way to go.